# Java PrintWriter: Why do we handle FileNotFoundException if the file is automatically created if not found?

Tags: java, file, printwriter

In the following SSCCE, I do not get a `FileNotFoundException` even if I delete this file from the given location/path i.e. `"D:\\Eclipse Workspaces\\SAMPLES AND OTHER SNIPPETS\\SoapCallResults.txt"`

Rather the `PrintWriter` seems to create the file if it is not found.

If the `Printwriter` creates the file if it is not found, why do we try to handle the `FileNotFoundException` (compiler complains if we don't surround it with `try/catch` or add a `throws` clause) when it is never going to be thrown?

```
package com.general_tests;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class PrintWriterFileNotFoundExceptionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myName = "What ever my name is!";
        PrintWriter printWriter = null;
        try {
            printWriter = new PrintWriter("D:\\Eclipse Workspaces\\SAMPLES AND OTHER SNIPPETS\\SoapCallResults.txt");
            printWriter.println(myName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (printWriter != null) { printWriter.close(); }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Documentations says: FileNotFoundException - If the given string does not denote an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or creating the file

Comment: Permissions, among other things, may prevent the writer from being able to create the file.

Comment: Downvoter: Please tell me the reason for the downvote, otherwise there are NO chances of IMPROVEMENT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Eclipse Workspaces` in your path with `foo` and see if you get the exception. The file itself may be created, but not the whole path above it.

You can also leave the path exactly as it is, but set read-only, hidden, and system attributes on the file. The OS will not be able to either write or create it.

Another variation: modify the file's ACL so your user doesn't have the write permission.

There are many more.

Answer (score 3):

`FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception, which simply translates that you will have to either catch it or add it in the throws clause.

I hope this answers your question about why we actually need it even though a file is created if not present-

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.File%29) -

`FileNotFoundException - If the given file object does not denote an existing, writable regular file and a new regular file of that name cannot be created, or if some other error occurs while opening or creating the file`

Comment: In which case, uour would think they could have named it UnableToCreateFileException.

Answer (score 1):

FIleNotFoundException is a checked exception. You need to handle these type of exceptions if your codeblock is throwing them. For unchecked type of exceptions, you don't have to handle (not mandatory). Can you really guarantee that the file is created, but not corrupted or the disk record isn't corrupted? Also, look into this - [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation).

Main thing is that your constructor is throwing FileNotFoundException (look here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#print%28char%29), which you have to catch (because it is checked).

Tips - For Eclipse, try and see what ctrl+SPACe reveals about an object's method. If your JavaDoc is in the right location, you will see all the explanation of what a method is doing including "Throws: SomeException" bit. This is what you need to look for when calling a method (i.e. whether you need try catch block for this).